# How to resolute root services in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have two root services.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MapControlsService {
    constructor(
        private portalBridgeService: PortalBridgeService,
    ) {}
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PortalBridgeService {
}
```

Why do I get error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PortalBridgeService' before initialization on the line:

`private portalBridgeService: PortalBridgeService`?

Comment: Do you have circular dependencies?

Comment: Nope. check out again, I added a few details

Comment: Are the two services in the same file? If so, the dependency needs to be defined before the dependent.

Comment: No, different files.

Comment: I think you could use a forwardRef, something like this: `constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => PortalBridgeService)) private portalBridgeService: PortalBridgeService) { ...`

Comment: I have simplified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't error self explanatory?

Try following:-

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class PortalBridgeService {}

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class MapControlsService {
  constructor(private portalBridgeService: PortalBridgeService) {}
}
```

Hope you get what was wrong there.